Divergence of vector field term-wise
In a spacetime $(M, g)$ the following identity for the divergence of a vector field $X$ holds
$$ \nabla_{\mu} X^{\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\det g}} \,
 \partial_{\mu} \big( \sqrt{- \det g} \ X^{\mu} \big)$$
Does this relation hold term-wise, e.g. does the above relation imply
$$ \nabla_0 X^0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\det g}} \ \partial_0 \big( \sqrt{- \det g} \ X^0 \big)$$
and similarly for indices 1,2,3; or does this relation hold only as a the whole sum?

are you familiar with Einstein's summation convention?

Yes I am aware that the first equation is summed over the index $\mu$ from 0 to 3. Thats why I am asking whether this relation does also (!) hold term-wise or only for the whole sums on both sides.

No, it does not hold; you can see the discussion in the comments under @Lukas Nullmeier’s answer for some conceptual remarks. But here’s a very concrete counterexample.
Consider polar coordinates in the plane and use the standard flat connection $\nabla$. Then, one can verify that for any vector field $X=X^r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+X^{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$, we have
\begin{align}
\nabla X&=\left(dX^r-rX^{\theta}\,d\theta\right)\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\left(dX^{\theta}+\frac{1}{r}X^{\theta}\,dr+\frac{1}{r}X^r\,d\theta\right)\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}.
\end{align}
In particular,
\begin{align}
\left(\nabla_{\partial_{\theta}}X\right)^{\theta}&=\frac{\partial X^{\theta}}{\partial\theta}+0 +\frac{X^r}{r}.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Even more particularly, if $X^{\theta}=0$ and $X^r\neq 0$, then
\begin{align}
(\nabla_{\partial_{\theta}}X)^{\theta}&=\frac{X^r}{r}\neq 0= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sqrt{|g|}X^{\theta}\right).
\end{align}
This shows the equality you’re asking about cannot hold.

Here are some remarks about how to compute the covariant derivative, in particular $(*)$: the most efficient way is to use Cartan’s method of moving frame to compute the connection 1-forms (see the approaches I suggest here on MSE of varying levels of difficulty, and adapt them to the non-orthonormal case I used here). Here, you could also use an Euler-Lagrange type argument to figure out the Christoffel symbols ($\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}=-r, \Gamma^{\theta}_{\theta r}=\Gamma^{\theta}_{r\theta}=\frac{1}{r}$ and all others vanish), then obtain $(*)$.

Ah, yes I see. Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, the other answer has already been deleted. I remembered it defining a new vector field, where every other component was set to zero and by that, the relation could be recovered. Do you remember what was the flaw there? Was it, that this new vector field was indeed not a vector field as it was not tensorial?

@Octavius essentially everything was wrong with it. Firstly, on a general manifold, there is no such ‘projection to $0^{th}$ axis’. Then they clarified they’re only working in a manifold covered by a single chart. Ok, in this case you can do this projection, but still this is troublesome because for the modified vector field $\tilde{X}$, we do not necessarily have $(\nabla_{\partial_0}\tilde{X})^0=(\nabla_{\partial_0}X)^0$ (and why would we even expect this? we’re taking derivatives of completely different objects).

Also, even without any of this, you should note that the Voss-Weyl formula (the divergence formula you quote), and in particular the presence of the metric determinant, comes up quite literally because of the Christoffel symbols which are being traced. Without this summation, they do not simplify to the metric determinant.

Ok, I think I understand. Thank you once again!
